# Comparing two containers for identity of their contents

Tags: python, containers, identity

I have a method that returns a set of objects, and I'm writing a unit test for this method. Is there a generic, tidy and idiomatic way of comparing these for identity (rather than equality)? Or do I need to write a suitable implementation myself?

An example (somewhat contrived to keep it simple):

```
class Foo(object):
    def has_some_property(self):
        ...

class Container(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo_set = set()

    def add_foo(self, foo):
        self.foo_set.add(foo)

    def foo_objects_that_have_property(self):
        return set([foo for foo in self.foo_set if foo.has_some_property()])

import unittest

class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def testFoo(self):
        c = Container()
        x, y, z = Foo(), Foo(), Foo()
        ...
        self.assertContentIdentity(c.foo_objects_that_have_property(), set([x, y]))
```

Importantly, testing here for equality won't do, since mutating the objects returned by `foo_objects_that_have_property()` may lead to inconsistent results depending on how those objects are used differently in `Container` even if they are "equal" at the time of the test.

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you're asking here. What objects are you trying to compare? Why should they be the same? Using `x is y` tests identity.

Comment: I want to discover if two containers (sets in this case) are identical and not just equal. `x is y` won't work here since that would tell me that the sets are different, which I know already. I want to know if the objects that they contain are the same objects or different objects.

Comment: Why does it matter that the objects are the same, as long as they're equal? Consider that the set, itself, considers equality rather than identity when determining if something is duplicated in the container. Also consider that the test for equality defaults to a test for identity, for user-defined types.

Comment: If I later mutate an object returned by `foo_object_that_have_property` in my example, then I could be mutating the wrong object if the test produces a false positive.

Comment: What is this supposed to test anyways? That no new items appear in the container out of thin air? Other tests probably cover that already ...

Comment: As I've said, it's a contrived example. In the general case, this is necessary for any test that needs to check that a function is returning the correct, expected _objects_ rather than just their values. Otherwise future mutations on those objects may not be correct.

Comment: You can (and should) test that whenever you add items to the container.

Answer (score 0):

The best I can come up with is:

```
@staticmethod
def set_id(c):
    return set([id(e) for e in c])

def assertContentIdentity(self, a, b):
    self.assertEqual(set_id(a), set_id(b))
```

However, this is specialised for sets and can't deal with nested containers.

Answer (score 0):

A simple, albeit not the most efficient, way to do it:

```
def assertContentIdentity(set1, set2):
    set1 = set([id(a) for a in set1])
    set2 = set([id(a) for a in set2])
    assert set1 == set2
```

Answer (score 0):

> x is y won't work here since that
>   would tell me that the sets are
>   different, which I know already. I
>   want to know if the objects that they
>   contain are the same objects or
>   different objects.

Then you need to write your own function, like

```
set([id(x) for x in X]) == set([id(y) for y in Y])
```